# Which predictive algorithm is most appropriate for a proceeding situation?

Tags: ai-design, prediction

I'm new to artificial intelligence. I am looking for the most appropriate AI solution for my application, which is developing an algorithm to predict a proceeding situation (edited: I want my algorithm to predict a situation or more than one to happen at a predefined moment) and, at the same time, to learn from the iterative stages of my application.

Any suggestions? Any help? Any proposals?

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by "predict a proceeding situation"? What is _proceeding situation_? Edit your post to clarify this.

Comment: @nbro: done editing.

Comment: I  still o not see any information in your question at all about the type of events to be predicted.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use a Sequence Processing Neural architecture - one option is a [recurrent network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network). These were specifically designed with your intent in mind.

They can consume sequences of data and learn from these in order to predict subsequent time-steps. Though these will require you to understand [best practices](https://towardsdatascience.com/10-things-to-think-about-before-starting-to-code-your-deep-neural-network-65094a1e7c08) for implementation.

If your task isn't too complex you could make use of a [forward algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_algorithm) or some variant. Many of these models make use of simplifying assumptions - if your use case cannot admit these you'll have to go for something more advanced.

If your prediction task is complex and requires **heavy** use of long term dependencies you may have to go for a more cutting edge architecture like a [transformer](https://ai.googleblog.com/2017/08/transformer-novel-neural-network.html) - but I heard that these are difficult to implement and most definitely require familiarity with deep learning systems.

Finally, if you need a system that can understand data and dependencies across **very large** spans of time then you may have to wait for the science to progress.

I hope this helps.